# SQL, Magic Quotes and 301 redirects - SQL injection risk?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

We're upgrading php to 5.5 and magic quotes are now deprecated, so we're removing them and converting to PDO where we haven't already.

However, I came across a situation where there is no query to convert and I'm trying to determine if my code is okay.

This page is purely a 301 redirect from an old legacy code.  This is basically the entire page code BEFORE:

```
<?php
$id = "0";
if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS["id"])) {
  $id = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $HTTP_GET_VARS["id"] : addslashes($HTTP_GET_VARS["id"]);
}

header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://example.com/newpage.php?id='.$id);
exit();

?>
<head>
</head>
```

Here's the new code that I converted it to.  I got rid of the magic stuff, also put in `ctype_digit ()` to validate the input as a positive integer.

Again, this is the entire code for the page:

```
<?php

// grab the variable
$rid = 1;
if (isset($_GET["id"]) && ctype_digit($_GET["id"])) // if the variable exists and is a positive integer
    {$rid = ($_GET["id"]);}
else
{
//die("This page doesn't exist");
}

header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://example.com/newpage.php?id='.$rid);
exit();

?>
<head>
</head>
```

So, my question(s):

1. Is this change reasonable and appropriate?
2. I don't think anything bad could be passed through since I'm using `ctype_digit()`, plus you can assume that `newpage.php` is using PDO queries.  Am I thinking about this correctly?

Thanks as always.

Comment: None of your excerpts is about SQL. And URL context would indicate `urlencode()` escaping.

Comment: Security risks can be well defined. On one hand, you suspect a security risk in the simple code you show, and on the other hand, you assume that using PDO will magically remove all security risks. This is not the case. All depends on how you are using it.

Comment: You have to start reasoning clearly about security topics. There's no magic. It is about escaping and validating user input and using the correct encodings and escape sequences.

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize your parameters in `newpage.php` again, before you pass them to the DB!

Comment: @LorenzMeyer - Thanks for the reply.  All due respect, but I'm attempting to reason clearly about these topics.  Obviously, I don't have the same understanding that you do, but I'm trying to learn and fix bad legacy code and I'm using stackoverflow as a resource to check my work.  I'm trying to learn!  I know there isn't any magic, I never said there was, so I guess I don't understand the tone of your response.  I'm just looking for feedback.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy - Thanks.  The newpage.php is converted over to PDO queries and the inputs are (hopefully) sanitized.

Comment: @Kevin I didn't mean to be harsh. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new code looks good.

More security is possible *before redirection*:

1) *Parse the id to an int:*

```
$rid = intval($_GET['id']);
```

See the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

2) *Check if the 'parsed' id exists in the database (or what you want)*